# Calling a function in Actionscript 3

Tags: function, actionscript-3

I am trying to call a function using the function name and ();  That is how I have done it in the past and how it is shown in examples on different sites. I get an error saying it is expecting 1 argument. Does calling a function require an argument?

Comment: Yes, some functions require arguments, and some don't. If you need further help, you should edit your question and add the code you were using.

Comment: No, not all functions require arguments -- expanding on @SunilD.'s reply.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have gone through your question you have said about calling function needed any argument here no needed they error says  expecting 1 argument means you want to pass the event name in the function here in this example i have shown..

```
//creating event listener for card movieclip 
 card_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);

 //In this function im passing the event name done (e:MouseEvent) likewise you want to do in the function then error will clear..
   function drag(e:MouseEvent):void
  {
   var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
   trace(mc.name);
   mc.startDrag();
 }
```

Thank You ...